# Spark: Joining with array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to join a dataframe with a string column to one with array of string so that if one of the values in the array is matched, the rows will join.

I tried this but I guess it's not support. 
Any other way to do this?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val left = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3)).toDF("col1")
val right = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((Array(1, 2), "Yes"),(Array(3),"No"))).toDF("col1", "col2")

left.join(right,"col1")
```

Throws:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:  cannot resolve '(`col1`
>   =`col1`)' due to data 
>   type mismatch: differing types in '(`col1` =
>
> `col1`)' (int and array).;;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to create an UDF for building your join condition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

val left = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3)).toDF("col1")
val right = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((Array(1, 2), "Yes"),(Array(3),"No"))).toDF("col1", "col2")

val checkValue = udf { 
  (array: WrappedArray[Int], value: Int) => array.contains(value) 
}
val result = left.join(right, checkValue(right("col1"), left("col1")), "inner")

result.show

+----+------+----+
|col1|  col1|col2|
+----+------+----+
|   1|[1, 2]| Yes|
|   2|[1, 2]| Yes|
|   3|   [3]|  No|
+----+------+----+
```

Comment: Well, I would guess this solution is slightly better, but I'm not sure because UDFs can be slow. Memory-wise, however, this solution would definitely use less space than the other one.

Comment: I guess I'll know better if I'll try both ways. Thank you.

Comment: @aclokay You can try to bicketize your DataFrames and then join by two conditions, bucketId and UDF. Then Spark will be able to Sort-Merge Join instead of Cartesian Join

Comment: @T.Gawęda What do you mean by _bickitize_?

Comment: @aclokay Bucketize - sorry for wrong name ;) It means, for example, you can add column with name bucketId and value = number of elements in array. Then join on a.bucketId == b.bucketId and udf - it should change query plan :)

Answer (score 10):

The most succinct way to do this is to use the array_contains spark sql expression as shown below, that said I've compared the performance of this with the performance of doing an explode and join as shown in a previous answer and the explode seems more performant.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
import spark.implicits._

val left = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("col1")

val right = Seq((Array(1, 2), "Yes"),(Array(3),"No")).toDF("col1", "col2").withColumnRenamed("col1", "col1_array")

val joined = left.join(right, expr("array_contains(col1_array, col1)")).show

+----+----------+----+
|col1|col1_array|col2|
+----+----------+----+
|   1|    [1, 2]| Yes|
|   2|    [1, 2]| Yes|
|   3|       [3]|  No|
+----+----------+----+
```

Note you can't use the org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_contains function directly as it requires the second argument to be a literal as opposed to a column expression.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `explode` on you Array column before the join. Explode creates a new line for each element in the array :

```
right = right.withColumn("exploded_col",explode(right("col1")))
right.show()

+------+----+--------------+
|  col1|col2|exploded_col_1|
+------+----+--------------+
|[1, 2]| Yes|             1|
|[1, 2]| Yes|             2|
|   [3]|  No|             3|
+------+----+--------------+
```

Then you can easily join with your first dataset.

Comment: Thanks! How does this compare to answer below.. performance wise?

Comment: @aclokay I think my answer is slower, especially if your arrays get large because you have to create (i.e. duplicate) a line for each element in the array.

Comment: I thought of this way too, but I hoped spark would do some magic to optimize this somehow. Thanks though!